# php get value from a form on previous page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble with getting values from radio buttons on a previous page. My current html + php code words fine with the search bar which is the first form below. However I want to be able to have radio button filters below the search bar.

```
 <section class="bar">
        <form action="/sub/search.php" method="post">
            <input type="test" name="criteria" placeholder="Search...">
            <button>Search</button>
        </form>
    </section><br>

    <form style="text-align:center" method="post" name="rb_filters">
        <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" value="1">1
        <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" value="2">2<br>
    </form>
```

In my php code I would like to run certain functions based on which radio button is checked.
So what I tried to do is this:

```
if($_POST['rb_filters']=='1')
{
     /* run code */
}
```

However it does not work =/ Any help would be much appreciated =D.

Comment: Two things; 2 forms and one with an action. The other, your 2nd form's name is the same as your radio buttons. Remove the the first `</form>` and `<form style="text-align:center" method="post" name="rb_filters">` and you should be in business.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the third put the radio buttons in the same button group

Comment: @Athafoud I'll let the OP figure out the rest of it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make it all one big form. The reason you're not seeing the `$_POST['rb_filters']` values is because the form they belong to was not submitted.

This should do:

```
<form action="/sub/search.php" method="post">
    <section class="bar">
        <input type="test" name="criteria" placeholder="Search..."/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </section>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" id="rb_filters_1" value="1"/>
        <label for="rb_filters_1">1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" id="rb_filters_2" value="2"/ >
        <label for="rb_filters_2">2</label>
    </p>
</form>
```

---

Some edits I made to your markup:

- Changed the button to a submit.
- Used labels for radios to make them easier to click
- Used some paragraphs instead of BR tags
- XHTML-ized since I'm all about XHTML
- General formatting

Comment: I don't think you understand.  The search bar is a separate form for a reason --- it is going to a search script.

Comment: @gview OP said "However I want to be able to have radio button filters below the search bar" which made me believe the radio buttons **are** part of the search. If I'm mistaken, OP can say so and I will delete my answer.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the radio button issue has nothing to do with the search script, but the OP hasn't exactly been active in responding to the comments already made.

Comment: Well, he's definitely checking for the radio buttons on a form submit (i.e. using `$_POST`) so I'm pretty confident my answer is relevant.

Comment: You don't know what script he is testing for input in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing question.

You either:

1. Have a script with 2 forms on it (one for search and another that is "self-posting").
2. Have a script with one form where you want to add the radio button to it, and post to the "search.php" script.

If you want #2 then look at The Maniac's answer.

If you want #1, then the problem is that you don't have a submit button.

```
<section class="bar">
    <form action="/sub/search.php" method="post">
        <input type="test" name="criteria" placeholder="Search...">
        <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</section><br>


<form style="text-align:center" method="post" name="rb_filters">
    <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" value="1">1
    <input type="radio" name="rb_filters" value="2">2<br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

While I agree with the prior comment that it's not a great idea to be naming separate objects the same (form name=rb_filters + input name = rb_filters), the fact of the matter is that the input is what will come through in the $_POST.

You can easily verify this by adding:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Whenever you are testing things like this, that is a good start to understand what is or is not happening with a form post.

Answer (score 0):

The post method submits data to a specific page based on what page you assign in the form action attribute. If you have two separate forms and one submit button, the form that the submit button is associated with will deliver to its action. However, in order to associate the values of the data in one form with the script you call for another, you are going to have to combine them into one form. you can still use your if statement and call a different script based on the value of $_POST['selected radio button name']. I am not quite understanding why you need two separate forms for the radio buttons and search bar. Aesthetics can easily be handled with CSS and the data posted to the action from one input will not interfere with that of another until you create a function to tell it to. Unless you mean that you want the radio buttons to update the search script while on the same page, hence no submit button. Then that will involve some jquery ajax to update the server side of your code. You would have to have a function that detects user side changes in the radio button selection and calls on an ajax script to update the pool from which your search bar draws.